# Laravel Job fail issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-jobs

I need queue job to re-run if it failed. I set `$tries = 3`
but I need to know if in job I catch exception is this will be considered as filed job and will be re-run?

Comment: Which command are you using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a Laravel job knows if a jobs has failed is one of the following two:

1. A job throws an exception which is NOT caught, resulting in the command failing with a big red text in the cli. (e.g. `throw new \RuntimeException('something went wrong');`
2. A job returns an error statuscode (e.g. `return -2;`)

I posted a more elaborate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108957/7528944)